# Plot approximately equal in geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I cannot realize how to put approximately equal symbol before the text inserted with `geom_text`. This works:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:2, y=1:2), aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label="10^10", x=1.5, y=1.5), parse=T)
```

If I put `%~~%` before the text

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:2, y=1:2), aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label="%~~%10^10", x=1.5, y=1.5), parse=T)
```

it returns an error: unexpected SPECIAL %~~%

I found several related questions but could not apply the given advices. I use package ggplot2_0.9.2.1. Package grDevices is also loaded.

Comment: it is a parse error. just I do parse('%') I get the same error.

Comment: Just as an aside, for adding only a single text label, you will probably want to use `annotate` instead.

Comment: Thanks. And what is the difference? Just convinience or something other?

Comment: People frequently get themselves into trouble using geom_text by inadvertently plotting many, many copies of their text label on top of each other, rather than just one, which makes the text look very ugly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will work with something on the left-hand site of the equation. This could also be `NULL`.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:2, y=1:2), aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() +
   geom_text(aes(label="NULL%~~%10^10", x=1.5, y=1.5), parse=T)
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Another solution is `label="phantom()%~~%10^10"`